# Php script which was running on background is not working

Tags: php, background, exec

I am trying to run a php script on background, which contains a simple mysql insert query. But it was not working.And I am running on windows machine. Below is the code to run script background.

```
function execInBackground($cmd){
    if (substr(php_uname(), 0, 7) == "Windows"){ 
        pclose(popen("start /B ". $cmd, "r"));  
    }else{ 
        exec($cmd . " > /dev/null &");   
    } 
}  
execInBackground('start cmd.exe @cmd /K php ping.php');
```

I gave file name to this script as background.php and I am trying to run the file via background is "ping.php". Which was also in the same directory. Below is the url I am trying to run on my localhost

```
http://localhost/adeptra/background.php
```

Where I am doing wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated

After debug , I found this issue in command prompt

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in D:\xampp\htdocs\adeptra\ping.php:10
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in D:\xampp\htdocs\adeptra\ping.php on line 10

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in D:\xampp\htdocs\adeptra\ping.php:10
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in D:\xampp\htdocs\adeptra\ping.php on line 10

D:\xampp\htdocs\adeptra>$conn = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
'$conn' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

I tried with mysql and mysqli both . Got same error
```

Comment: _"and I am trying to run the file via background is "ping.php""_? What does that mean? Also, please explain what _"not working"_ means. Errors? Not inserting? Inserting wrong content? Computer crashes? What have you done to debug it?

Comment: Is the script not running or not inserting the queries?

Comment: I mean, I am referring this one execInBackground('php ping.php'); This ping.php is having some insert queries.

Comment: So how do you know if its not running? because no data is inserted?

Comment: not inserting records in the related table.

Comment: @user3408779  Can you please share your code for **ping.php**

Comment: Are you sure there are no errors in ping.php?

Comment: Yes, when I directly call ping.php , records got inserted in the related table.

Comment: Add some logging in your files and check what happens and where it stops working. Since you're executing this through a web server, make sure that the web server user (which will be the one that will execute the command in the background) has access to execute that command, check if `php` exists in the users environment (having the correct PATH setup) and that the path to `ping.php` is correct. I would recommend that you use absolute paths to both `php` and the `ping.php`-file.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson, I have edited my question and added the error I am getting, Please check..

Comment: The `mysql_*`-extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5 (in 2013) and completely removed in PHP 7 (in 2015). Use MySQLi or PDO instead. You said that you've tried ping.php directly. Was that through the web server or through CLI? Try it through CLI and check if it works then.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your suggestion. I will check.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check below code it will help you. It's work for me. You can check here same http://php.net/manual/en/function.popen.php

```
function execInBackground($cmd){
    if (substr(php_uname(), 0, 7) == "Windows"){ 
        $timer = popen("start /B ". $cmd, "r"); 
        sleep(15);
        pclose($timer);
    }else{ 
        exec($cmd . " > /dev/null &");   
    } 
}

execInBackground("php ping.php");
```

Comment: I have edited my question and added the output.Please check

Comment: @user3408779 I have checked your updated question this code is proper. can you please update your ping.php file code in your question.